# Geometry Nodes: Draw Curve from Point 0 to Point 2 of Geometry. (Blender3.0)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to draw an inscribed 7 side polygon (centred on 0,0,0), where a curve goes from each point through the origin to the 2nd next point; for example point 0 (through origin(0,0,0)) to point 2.

Psuedocode would be:

```
For each point 
    draw curve from prevI to nextI
```

Problem:
Curve takes vector start, and vector end.

I am able to get the prevI and nextI but how do I access the vector position for that Index (to give to my curve)?
[image: heptagon]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand your question.
Do you want to do something like in one of examples below?

**Example_1.**

[image]

Here Curve Line center point is at 0.0.0. And Curve Line endpoints are dropped to the nearest points of the Curve Circle.

**Example_2.**

[image]

Here Curve Line center point is at 0.0.0. And Curve Line endpoints are dropped to the N and N+1 points of the Curve Circle.

**Example_3.**

[image]

Here cyclic spline do seven loops.